# Tracking CPU time of Python process and children

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Is there an easy way to track the CPU time of not only a Process but of any child processes launched by it?

I tried sub-classing `multiprocessing.Process` to time an arbitrary function, like:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Process

class TimedProcess(Process):

    daemon = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TimedProcess, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.t0 = time.clock()

    @property
    def duration_seconds(self):
        return time.clock() - self.t0

p = TimedProcess(target=my_long_running_func)
p.start()
while p.is_alive():
    print p.duration_seconds
    time.sleep(1)
```

However, when I tried to time functions involving Scikits-learn or other code involving c-extensions or sub-processes, I found my `duration_sections` would often report 0, or just a few seconds, even though the code would run for hours. How would I fix this?

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg, I've used that a little in the past. Do you have any specific feature in mind? It doesn't seem to contain an explicit method for this, but I could imagine building one from their `Process.get_children()` and `cpu_times()` methods.

Comment: If you're looking to get the value of `time.clock()` from inside the process, you're going to have to send it from one process to another, for example with `multiprocessing.Queue`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code almost prints the CPU time, but you're calling `time.clock()` in the parent process instead of the child process. By using `multiprocessing.Pipe`, you can pass the values from the child to the parent process:

```
import time
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe

class TimedProcess(Process):

    daemon = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TimedProcess, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.parent_conn, self.child_conn = Pipe()
        self.child_finished = False
        self._duration = 0.0

    def get_duration(self):
        if not self.child_finished:
            self.parent_conn.send(None)
            result = self.parent_conn.recv()
            if result == 'done':
                self.child_finished = True
            else:
                self._duration = result
        return self._duration

    def run(self):
        try:
            t0 = time.clock()
            Thread(target=self._run).start()
            while True:
                request = self.child_conn.recv()
                self.child_conn.send(time.clock() - t0)
                if request == 'stop':
                    break
        finally:
            self.child_conn.send('done')

    def _run(self):
        try:
            super(TimedProcess, self).run()
        finally:
            self.parent_conn.send('stop')

p = TimedProcess(target=my_long_running_func)
p.start()
while p.is_alive():
    time.sleep(1)
    print p.get_duration()
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but this seems very inefficient. You don't need to get clock() from inside each process. You can read the user time for any process from `/proc/stat` or `/proc/<pid>/stat` on Linux, which would be a lot faster since it avoids the interprocess IO.